# Can I prevent a specific bone from moving during Auto-IK posing?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

Can I limit chain length during Auto-IK posing, or otherwise prevent the movement of specific bones?

I'm familiar with the ability to limit chain length when setting IK bone constraints, but I don't see any similar option while posing with Auto-IK enabled. Is there such a feature, or other way to lock a specific bone from moving during Auto-IK?

Answer (score 1):

In *Bone* settings (Pose mode) find IK controls. Don't mind that they are greyed out, they are still working. Lock these axis (click on "lock icon") to fully exclude desired bones from the IK chain.

**How to quickly lock many bones?**

Select desired bones and lock axis as described earlier, then click on "lock icon" with right mouse button and select `Copy to selected`, repeat for every axis (X,Y,Z)

[image]